# Does the rhythm act as a catch-all category in variation changes

Tags: piano, rhythm

Isn't rhythm by itself a categorical term in theme and variations

Comment: I'm unclear on what is meant by "a categorical term". Could you give an example of how such a term might be used?

Comment: This needs to be made clearer for us mere mortals! What exactly are you asking as far as theme and variations are concerned?

Comment: Welcome! Please use the "Edit" button under the question to explain a bit more. I *think* you're asking: "If someone uses the same melody but only changes rhythm, does it count as a variation?" In that case, I'm afraid the answer is that there's no official rule about what "counts." If you're asking because you're working on an assignment or test about variations, you might have to ask the teacher to clarify what they want.